# "capture image from webcam" Again

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webcam

I want to capture image from webcam using c#, asp.net web application.

Can somebody provide me a sample code to do this?

Comment: Did you even _try_ google first? There's a ton of search hits on webcam asp.net c# out there...

Comment: i tried there, but i'm not getting a simple solution for my asp.net c# web application

Comment: -1: this is not a "show me da codez" site.

Answer (score 0):

I think that only Flash has webcam support (it has something like: var c=Camera.get();movieControl.attachVideo(c); - but don't know about transferring video stream to server). You need some client scripting, which has nothing to do with server side of story, it could be asp.net, php, ruby, ...